# Simply connected homology cobordisms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, cobordism

I'm looking for interesting examples of a homology 3-sphere $Y$ for which there exists a smooth, simply connected homology cobordism from $Y$ to itself (or simply to another homology 3-sphere $Y'$, since one can then just double along either end). By "interesting," I mean that $Y$ isn't known to bound a contractible manifold (or, better yet, is known not to bound contractible, but that's probably much harder), since in that case there's clearly a simply connected homology cobordism to $S^3$. I'm preferably but not exclusively interested in Seifert fibered examples.

There are lots of known obstructions (e.g. *Taubes, Clifford Henry*, [**Gauge theory on asymptotically periodic 4-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214440981), J. Differ. Geom. 25, 363-430 (1987). [ZBL0615.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0615.57009) and *Fintushel, Ronald; Stern, Ronald J.*, [**Instanton homology of Seifert fibred homology three spheres**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-61.1.109), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 61, No.1, 109-137 (1990). [ZBL0705.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0705.57009)), but I haven't managed to find any positive results in the literature, apart from constructions of homology spheres which do bound contractible manifolds (e.g. *Casson, Andrew J.; Harer, John L.*, [**Some homology lens spaces which bound rational homology balls**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1981.96.23), Pac. J. Math. 96, 23-36 (1981). [ZBL0483.57017](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0483.57017)). Has anyone ever produced such an example?

Comment: It sounds like if you could construct such an example, it would give a periodic homotopy $S^3 \times \mathbb{R}$. You probably know that Freedman gave a construction of a homotopy $S^3 \times \mathbb{R}$ with a Poincaré sphere cross-section (although this paper is not very well-cited, since his more spectacular work came shortly after). But I'm not sure if one can find a cobordism like you're looking for in his example. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=541336

Comment: Right - you could glue the ends together to get a homotopy $S^3 \times S^1$, and the take the cover. But it's not possible to do this with the Poincare sphere, thanks to Taubes's periodic ends theorem.